# Calculating compounding investment returns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a data frame that calculates profit/loss per investment. This is based on a 10% risk profile on the initial account size (for example: 5000 USD). In case of profit of trade x I would like to add that profit to the account size. In case of loss I need to subtract this loss from the account size. The new account size should be used for the next trade, and so on.

What would be the best way to do this.

Columns I have in my dataframe:
Trade #
AccountSize
MaxRisk
PositionSize
Profit/Loss
Cumulative P/L

So basically for each subsequent row I would like to add the Profit/Loss value to the AccountSize column, and change/recalculate the PositionSize for the next record, and so on and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code as well.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.financial.html may of use